# Code to make selection of text and delete it

Tags: vba, excel, selection

I'm trying to create a macro to look for to specific expressions and remove that content.
For example I need to remove everything that goes from the word "NOTIFICATION" to the expression "Good Morning" (but keeping "Good Morning, if possible).

I have a code to remove one line, but cannot figure out how to do it with a selection, because I don't have the same number of lines every time. Could be 3 or up to 9, more or less.

The code I have is like this (I've removed the parts of the code that did other things that are not related to this problem I have):

```
    Private Sub ProcessMsg(msg As MailItem)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandlerProcessMsg

    Dim msg2 As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim msgDoc As Word.Document
    Dim msgDoc2 As Word.Document
    Dim objSel As Word.Selection

    Set msg2 = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set msgDoc = msg.GetInspector.WordEditor
    Set msgDoc2 = msg2.GetInspector.WordEditor

    msgDoc.Select
    msgDoc.Windows(1).Selection.Copy
    msgDoc2.Windows(1).Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault

    Set objSel = msgDoc2.Windows(1).Selection
    With objSel
        .Find.Execute "NOTIFICATION"
        .Collapse wdCollapseStart
        .MoveEnd WdUnits.wdStory, 1
        .Delete
    End With

    Set objSel = msgDoc2.Windows(1).Selection
    With objSel
        .MoveStart WdUnits.wdStory, -1
        .Collapse wdCollapseStart
        .MoveEnd WdUnits.wdParagraph, 1
        .Delete
    End With


    Set msgDoc = Nothing
    Set msgDoc2 = Nothing
    Set objSel = Nothing
    Set msg2 = Nothing

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandlerProcessMsg:
    Set msgDoc = Nothing
    Set msgDoc2 = Nothing
    Set objSel = Nothing
    Set msg2 = Nothing
    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
End Sub
```

Could anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want (from what I understand). Just paste this function inside one of the word document's code objects and run it (have tried on Word, rather than Excel). It's mainly to show you how you could go by handling such a problem.

```
Sub LineRemover()

    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    Dim myParagraph As Paragraph
    Dim mySentences As Sentences
    Dim mySentence As Range

    Dim deleted As Boolean
    deleted = False

    For Each myParagraph In doc.Paragraphs

        Set mySentences = myParagraph.Range.Sentences
        For Each mySentence In mySentences

            If InStr(mySentence, "Good morning") <> 0 Then
                    '"Good morning" is present inside this line; exit the loop!

                    Exit For

            ElseIf deleted Then
                    '"NOTIFICATION" was already deleted, need to remove all subsequent lines!

                mySentence.Delete

            ElseIf InStr(mySentence, "NOTIFICATION") <> 0 Then
                    '"NOTIFICATION" is present inside this line; delete it!

                mySentence.Delete
                deleted = True 'Tell the program you've deleted it!

            End If

        Next

        If deleted Then
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

**Extra details :**  `InStr(String1, String2)` will return the position at which `String2` is found inside `String1`